# How to deeply remove keys in object?

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

I have this json object returned from an API that has a few quirks, and I'd like to normalize it so I can process the input the same for every response. These means getting rid of superfluous keys:

#### Response:

```
{
  _links: {...},
  _embedded: {
    foo: [
      {
        id: 2,
        _embedded: {
          bar: []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I'd like to remove all the `_embedded` keys and flatten it, like so:

```
{
  _links: {...},
  foo: [
    {
      id: 2,
      bar: []
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what I have at the moment, but it only works for the top level and I don't think it'll play well with arrays.

```
_.reduce(temp1, function(accumulator, value, key) {
  if (key === '_embedded') {
    return _.merge(accumulator, value);
  }
  return accumulator[key] = value;
}, {})
```

Comment: This work for you? http://codepen.io/fa7ad/pen/Raaaeo?editors=0011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
function unEmbed(data) { 
  return _.reduce(data, function(accumulator, value, key) {
    const returnableValue = _.isObject(value) ? unEmbed(value) : value;
    if (key === 'embedded') {
      return _.merge(accumulator, returnableValue);
    }
    accumulator[key] = returnableValue;
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
}
```

Problem before I was returning `return accumulator[key] = returnableValue`, which worked out to be `return returnableValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Loop in recursion on all of your keys, once you see a key which start with `_`
simply remove it.

## ***`Code:`***

```
var
// The keys we want to remove from the Object
        KEYS_TO_REMOVE = ['_embedded'],

// The data which we will use
        data = {
            _links: {'a': 1},
            _embedded: {
                foo: [
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        _embedded: {
                            bar: []
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        _embedded: {
                            bar: [
                                {
                                    id: 4,
                                    _embedded: {
                                        bar: []
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        };

/**
 * Flatten the given object and remove the desired keys if needed
 * @param obj
 */
function flattenObject(obj, flattenObj) {

    var key;

    // Check to see if we have flatten obj or not
    flattenObj = flattenObj || {};

    // Loop over all the object keys and process them
    for (key in obj) {

        // Check that we are running on the object key
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            // Check to see if the current key is in the "black" list or not
            if (KEYS_TO_REMOVE.indexOf(key) === -1) {

                // Process the inner object without this key
                flattenObj[key] = flattenObject(obj[key], flattenObj[key]);
            } else {
                flattenObject(obj[key], flattenObj);
            }

        }
    }

    return flattenObj;


}

console.log(flattenObject(data));
```

Comment: I think i made a somewhat half-assed not-so-terrible implementation [here](http://codepen.io/fa7ad/pen/Raaaeo?editors=0012).  Pull up the console to see

Comment: I get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` when I call that on my test object.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you already have almost all of the code you need. All we have to do is wrap it in a function so we can use recursion. You'll see we only add a check to see if it is an object, if it is, we already have a function that knows how to flatten that object, so we'll just call it again with the key that we need to flatten.

```
function flatten(temp1) {  // Wrap in a function so we can use recursion
  return _.reduce(temp1, function(accumulator, value, key) {
    if (key === '_embedded') {
      return _.merge(accumulator, value);
    } else if (value !== null && typeof value === 'object') // Check if it's another object
      return _.merge(accumulator, flatten(value)) // Call our function again
    return accumulator[key] = value;
  }, {})
}
```

I'll be able to test it in a bit, but this should be what you need.

Comment: That's something like I had that I didn't post, it throws an error after it encounters the second `_embedded`, and I think you want to check if `value` is an object, not the `key`.